# RStudio error message object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: rstudio, correlation

I am a newbie with RStudio and I am doing some exercises to learn about.

I want to calculate correlation between 2 variables of a dataset and I am using this code

```
library(nycflights13)
by_carrier <- group_by(flights,carrier)
new_table <- summarise(by_carrier, max_mean_delay = mean(dep_delay,na.rm = TRUE), num_flights = n())  %>%
  ggplot(aes(num_flights,max_mean_delay,label = num_flights)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1)
cor[new_table$num_flights,new_table$max_mean_delay]
```

I got the graph I wanted fut when trying to calculate correlation I am getting following error message

```
Error in cor[new_table$num_flights, new_table$max_mean_delay] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I have read several post related to same error but honestly I don't get what RStudio is reporting, what is my mistake.

I appreciate any help on this

Thank you